# Access DSUM Issue

Tags: function, ms-access, sum

I am trying to use Dsum function in a query field to create subtotals of volume per each channel

Exp1: DSUM("[vol_tot]","[TBLNAME]","[CH]")

I have the following results:

```
CH Exp1
10 200,000
20 200,000
30 200,000
```

I was expecting:

```
CH Exp2
10 100,000
20 40,000
30 60,000
```

I'm trying to attain the same functionality as a SUMIF function in Excel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter criteria argument is incomplete. Try:

`DSUM("[vol_tot]","[TBLNAME]","[CH]=" & [CH])`

Domain argument functions can perform slowly in query and textbox. Consider building a report using its Grouping and Sorting feature and =Sum() in textbox.

Comment: the provided formula gives an error, and when I put quotes on the second [CH] I get same results as before.

Comment: What error? Both of these techniques work for me. Is [CH] a number type field? No quotes around the second [CH]. This is variable parameter. Concatenate variables. Edit your question to post the complete SQL statement. Report is really better approach.

Comment: CH field was short text.  I changed it to number and your syntax worked a charm!  Could you describe how I can use Report approach instead?

Comment: You should reference tutorials on building Access report using Sorting and Grouping with aggregate calcs.