# MS Access: DSUM to sum only rows with same date

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have the following query where week is a date field, market and team are text strings.

```
SELECT t1.Week, t1.Market, t1.Team, Sum(t1.Audits) AS CFS_Audits, Sum(t1.Incorrect) AS CFS_Incorrect
FROM t1
GROUP BY t1.Week, t1.Market, t1.Team;
```

My goal is to have one addditional field that uses `DSUM` to calculate all audits that occurred on a given week. The field should thus have a lower granularity than CFS_Audits which is broken down at Week-Market-Team level.
I tried the following code `X: DSUM("Audits", "t1", "[Week]="&[Week])` which was suggested in the closest question I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009990/access-dsum-issue) but the resulting field is consistently `NULL`. I suspect this might be because in the given example the field was stored as a numeral and not as a date. Or maybe I am taking the wrong approach altogether.
Tutorials online also did not help as in all cases I have found they offer examples of the criteria parameter of `DSUM`with a hard-coded criteria whereas here I need a row-by-row evaluation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in Access SQL are pretty hard to work with

The easiest way is to avoid any typecasting, is to use a subquery instead of a domain aggregate.

```
SELECT t.Week, t.Market, t.Team, Sum(t.Audits) AS CFS_Audits, Sum(t.Incorrect) AS CFS_Incorrect, (SELECT Sum(s.Audits) FROM t1 s WHERE s.Week = t.Week) As X
FROM t1 t
GROUP BY t.Week, t.Market, t.Team;
```

Alternatively, you can use a date in your `DSUM`, but it should be surrounded by `#` octothorpes and either formatted YYYY-MM-DD or MM/DD/YYYY:

```
SELECT t.Week, t.Market, t.Team, Sum(t.Audits) AS CFS_Audits, Sum(t.Incorrect) AS CFS_Incorrect, DSUM("Audits", "t1", "[Week]=" & Format([Week], "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#") As X
FROM t1 t
GROUP BY t.Week, t.Market, t.Team;
```

Comment: Thank you,
During the thought process I honestly did not think of using a subquery in the `SELECT`statement. Since I will have to repeat this sort of logic at many more levels of "intermediate granularity" it might be much more efficient than having a `DSUM` for each.